# Android checkbox hack causes moving site on iPhone

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone

I have been using the [Advanced checkbox hack](http://timpietrusky.com/advanced-checkbox-hack) to hide and show my responsive menu. The hack is necessary to allow Android <4.1.2 to actually tap the toggle--it doesn't work without the hack.

Now it turns out that the animation part of the hack

```css
body { 
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { 
  from {padding:0;} 
  to {padding:0;} 
}
```

causes actual movement in at least an iPhone. How do I prevent this hack from ruining the site experience for iPhone users?

I have a preview live with the error [over here](http://bakabaka.nl/preview/leefh/). A movie with the error visible is seen [here](http://bakabaka.nl/temp/VID-20150915-WA0003.mp4).

Comment: Have you tried other properties that don't do anything? Like `transform:translate(0px)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had a css rule `* { transition: all .5s ease; }` css rule to  apply to all animations—including this hack. This caused the bug.

Removing this rule and manually applying its contents to all my animations fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have an Android to test this but wont the hack also work when just applied to one element instead of the entire body?

```
.toggle {
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  from { padding: 0; }
  to { padding: 0; }
}
```

As long as you don’t have any padding on that element